# how to get a particular value from erlang JSON

Tags: erlang

I have following from GCM

```
{[
    {<<"multicast_id">>,888},
    {<<"success">>,0},
    {<<"failure">>,1},
    {<<"canonical_ids">>,0},
        {<<"results">>,
            [
                {
                    [
                        {<<"error">>,<<"NotRegistered">>}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]}
```

I am trying to read "NotRegistered". But I am not able to find a way to read it.

How can I read "NotRegistered"?

I tried

```
result_from(Json) ->
    {
      proplists:get_value(<<"multicast_id">>, Json),
      proplists:get_value(<<"success">>, Json),
      proplists:get_value(<<"failure">>, Json),
      proplists:get_value(<<"canonical_ids">>, Json),
      proplists:get_value(<<"results">>, Json)
    }.
```

but I get an exception

> CRASH REPORT Process `''` with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no
>   function clause matching `proplists:get_value(<<"results">>,{[{<<"multicast_id">>,888},{<<"success">>,0},{<<"failure">>,1},{<<"canonical_ids">>,...},...]}, undefined)` line 226 in `p1_server:terminate/7` line 874

Comment: any sample code that you tried to read..

Comment: you should try these http://www.jsonquerytool.com/, http://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this is not JSON, but a data structure most JSON libraries use as a structure that best translates to and from JSON. Officially this is a [tuple()](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id68762) with one element: a list.

You get this error, because the get_value function does not have a clause for your arguments, meaning one of the arguments might be malformatted. The error is correct in that the Json argument's type is wrong.

The Json variable is not a proplist. Convert the structure to a (prop)list like so:

```
{List} = Json,
```

And then use this as the proplists:get_value's 2nd argument.

The 2nd argument must be a list of [properties](http://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#type-property) ie. of type `[property()]`, but you're providing `{[property()]}` instead.